# Can postfix detect its ip/domain is marked as spam by an e-mail provider?

Tags: header, spam, postfix-mta

Is it possible to detect in postfix that a sending IP is spammed by a receiving mailbox like gmail/yahoo/outlook/hotmail etc?

For example if a receiver spams my sender domain or an IP is blacklisted or sending address is spammed.

Where do I read reply headers in postfix?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Reporting of an email as spam to a webmail provider is handled entirely within that providers' systems. The report is between the sending and the webmail provider.

Reporting an email as spam to the service provider of the spam origin generally goes upstream of the machine that actually sent the spam out (and if it isn't, it will be in the form of an email to an administrator's mailbox so you should look there).

Reports to a blacklist are between the reporter and the blacklist. You can monitor the blacklists (using whatever APIs they provide) to see if your IP appears on them.

Comment: Thanks for the info
Two Questions:
1- (Related) Is Feedback Loop a good idea for spam/junk detection?
2- (Unrelated)How to detect hard bounce of an email sent by my server? One possible way is to read the subject field of the return email informing that the mail could not be delivered and reading the body of the mail after that looking for the reason the mail could not be delivered.
But the issue with this is that there are many email providers and they might use different formats to return information about the error and involves overhead. So I am looking for a workaround on that.